# Hide a controller with `dat.gui`

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I have the following code for a simple GUI (also in [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Peque/vwn93h1s/)):

```js
import { GUI } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.112.1/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js";

var gui;
var settings = {
  toggle: true,
  slide: 0.0,
  child: 0.0,
}

function toggle() {
  if (!settings.toggle) {
    gui.__folders.Parent.hide();
  } else {
    gui.__folders.Parent.show();
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  gui = new GUI();
  gui.add(settings, 'toggle').onChange(toggle);;
  gui.add(settings, 'slide', -1, 1);
  var folder = gui.addFolder('Parent');
  folder.add(settings, 'child', -1, 1);
  folder.open();
};
```

Note how I made the `toggle` button hide/show the `Parent` folder easily.

Is there a way I could do the same with a controller? In particular, could I make the toggle button hide/show the `slide` controller instead of the `Parent` folder?

Ideally, I should be able to do this using the `slide` name, instead of relying on the position where the controller is within the list of controllers in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that (if it's not too late for an answer):

```js
var gui;
var settings = {
  toggle: true,
  slide: 0.0,
  child: 0.0,
}

function getController(name) {
  let controller = null;
  let controllers = gui.__controllers;
  for (let i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
    let c = controllers[i];
    if (c.property == name || c.name == name) {
      controller = c;
      //console.log(c);
      break;
    }
  }
  return controller;
}

function toggle() {
  if (!settings.toggle) {
    getController("slide").__li.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    getController("slide").__li.style.display = "";
  }
}

gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(settings, 'toggle').onChange(toggle);;
gui.add(settings, 'slide', -1, 1);
var folder = gui.addFolder('Parent');
folder.add(settings, 'child', -1, 1);
folder.open();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.112.1/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Never too late. Thank you very much! ^^

Comment: @Peque You're welcome :) Good to know, that it helped.

Comment: Hope one day it will be easier... https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/issues/259 :-D